# TestStack.White - using SearchCriteria.ByNativeProperty

Tags: c#, teststack, automationelement

Analysing with UI Spy, I want to get the following element:
[image]

Looking at all this parameter, the "LabeledBy" parameter seems to be
the best parameter to identify the element. I'm using TestStack.White
for my automation and tried it that way:

`TestStack.White.UIItems.IUIItem[] IUIArr = GetMainWindow().GetMultiple(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByNativeProperty(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.LabeledByProperty, NUnit.Framework.Is.EqualTo(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByNativeProperty(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.NameProperty, "NLP*"))));`
`GetMainWindow()` is a function, returning the MainWindow of the application and it is working correctly.

My main problem is, that I get an exception with the text `Der PropertyCondition-Wert für die AutomationElementIdentifiers.LabeledByProperty-Eigenschaft muss "AutomationElement" sein` what means translated something like `The value for property condition of an AutomationElementIdentifier.LabeledByPropery has to bei "AutomationElement"`

My second and not soooo important question is: Do I really need to reference NUnit only for that one Is.EqualTo-Function? Usually I try to avoid referencing external DLLs, only for one method.

Unfortunatelly, I'm not so skilled using the nativ `System.Windows.Automation` library, but a solution without TestStack.White would also be helpful.